# Triggering a function without event target to display modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to trigger the login/register modal to appear based on an ajax response. The current example I have only displays the modal when the login or register button is clicked. I'm not sure how to trigger the modal without passing it an object. I'm sure there is a clean way to call the display function, I just don't know how.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/api/user/add.php",
  data: "xxx=xxx",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    var responseText = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))['response'];

    switch (responseStatus) {  
      case 'success':
        $('#notifyDiv').attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
        break;  
      case 'error':
        $('#notifyDiv').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
        break;
      case 'loginError':
        $('#notifyDiv').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
        //Show sign in/register modal.
        break;   
      default:
    }

    $('#notifyDiv').animate({
      opacity: 100
    }, 2000);

    $('#notifyDiv').text(responseText);
    
    $('#notifyDiv').animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

```js
(function() {
  //Login/Signup modal window - by CodyHouse.co
  function ModalSignin(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.blocks = this.element.getElementsByClassName('js-signin-modal-block');
    this.switchers = this.element.getElementsByClassName('js-signin-modal-switcher')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
    this.triggers = document.getElementsByClassName('js-signin-modal-trigger');
    this.hidePassword = this.element.getElementsByClassName('js-hide-password');
    this.init();
  };

  ModalSignin.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    //open modal/switch form
    for (var i = 0; i < this.triggers.length; i++) {
      (function(i) {
        self.triggers[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          if (event.target.hasAttribute('data-signin')) {
            event.preventDefault();
            self.showSigninForm(event.target.getAttribute('data-signin'));
          }
        });
      })(i);
    }

    //close modal
    this.element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (hasClass(event.target, 'js-signin-modal') || hasClass(event.target, 'js-close')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        removeClass(self.element, 'cd-signin-modal--is-visible');
      }
    });
    //close modal when clicking the esc keyboard button
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      (event.which == '27') && removeClass(self.element, 'cd-signin-modal--is-visible');
    });

    //hide/show password
    for (var i = 0; i < this.hidePassword.length; i++) {
      (function(i) {
        self.hidePassword[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          self.togglePassword(self.hidePassword[i]);
        });
      })(i);
    }

    //IMPORTANT - REMOVE THIS - it's just to show/hide error messages in the demo
    this.blocks[0].getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      self.toggleError(document.getElementById('signin-email'), true);
    });
    this.blocks[1].getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      self.toggleError(document.getElementById('signup-username'), true);
    });
  };

  ModalSignin.prototype.togglePassword = function(target) {
    var password = target.previousElementSibling;
    ('password' == password.getAttribute('type')) ? password.setAttribute('type', 'text'): password.setAttribute('type', 'password');
    target.textContent = ('Hide' == target.textContent) ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
    putCursorAtEnd(password);
  }

  ModalSignin.prototype.showSigninForm = function(type) {
    // show modal if not visible
    !hasClass(this.element, 'cd-signin-modal--is-visible') && addClass(this.element, 'cd-signin-modal--is-visible');
    // show selected form
    for (var i = 0; i < this.blocks.length; i++) {
      this.blocks[i].getAttribute('data-type') == type ? addClass(this.blocks[i], 'cd-signin-modal__block--is-selected') : removeClass(this.blocks[i], 'cd-signin-modal__block--is-selected');
    }
    //update switcher appearance
    var switcherType = (type == 'signup') ? 'signup' : 'login';
    for (var i = 0; i < this.switchers.length; i++) {
      this.switchers[i].getAttribute('data-type') == switcherType ? addClass(this.switchers[i], 'cd-selected') : removeClass(this.switchers[i], 'cd-selected');
    }
  };

  ModalSignin.prototype.toggleError = function(input, bool) {
    // used to show error messages in the form
    toggleClass(input, 'cd-signin-modal__input--has-error', bool);
    toggleClass(input.nextElementSibling, 'cd-signin-modal__error--is-visible', bool);
  }

  var signinModal = document.getElementsByClassName("js-signin-modal")[0];
  if (signinModal) {
    new ModalSignin(signinModal);
  }

  // toggle main navigation on mobile
  var mainNav = document.getElementsByClassName('js-main-nav')[0];
  if (mainNav) {
    mainNav.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (hasClass(event.target, 'js-main-nav')) {
        var navList = mainNav.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        toggleClass(navList, 'cd-main-nav__list--is-visible', !hasClass(navList, 'cd-main-nav__list--is-visible'));
      }
    });
  }

  //class manipulations - needed if classList is not supported
  function hasClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList) return el.classList.contains(className);
    else return !!el.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)'));
  }

  function addClass(el, className) {
    var classList = className.split(' ');
    if (el.classList) el.classList.add(classList[0]);
    else if (!hasClass(el, classList[0])) el.className += " " + classList[0];
    if (classList.length > 1) addClass(el, classList.slice(1).join(' '));
  }

  function removeClass(el, className) {
    var classList = className.split(' ');
    if (el.classList) el.classList.remove(classList[0]);
    else if (hasClass(el, classList[0])) {
      var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + classList[0] + '(\\s|$)');
      el.className = el.className.replace(reg, ' ');
    }
    if (classList.length > 1) removeClass(el, classList.slice(1).join(' '));
  }

  function toggleClass(el, className, bool) {
    if (bool) addClass(el, className);
    else removeClass(el, className);
  }

  //credits http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/move-cursor-to-end-of-textarea-or-input/
  function putCursorAtEnd(el) {
    if (el.setSelectionRange) {
      var len = el.value.length * 2;
      el.focus();
      el.setSelectionRange(len, len);
    } else {
      el.value = el.value;
    }
  };
})();
```

I have tried just calling,

`self.showSigninForm(event.target.getAttribute('data-signin'));` but don't have an event target to pass for it to work.

Comment: I'm guessing type specifies if it displays the login or registration screen.

Comment: Have you tried manually triggering a event on a button that opens the modal? With jquery `$('.btn-modal-open').trigger('click);` change the selector to appropriate one.